# JavaScript: "onmouseenter"-Function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning some HTML, CSS, and JavaScript on my own at the moment.
I have some trouble understanding the use of a function.

I have a div style="display: none" inside of another div. The "style.display" of the first div is set to "block" when the user enters the first div with his mouse. When he leaves it the "style.display" of the second div is set to "none" again.
Now the problem is that one function should do this to all of the divs of this kind. The HTML looks like that:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="box box2" onmouseenter="show(this)" onmouseleave="hide()">
      <b>HTML</b>

      <div class="expl expl2" style="display:none" id="test">
        <ul>
          <li><b>Software</b></li>
          <li><i>HTML</i></li>
          <li>HTML, CSS, JavaScript...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="box box2" onmouseenter="show(this)" onmouseleave="hide2()">
      <b>HTML</b>

      <div class="expl expl2" style="display:none" id="test2">
        <ul>
          <li><b>Software</b></li>
          <li><i>CSS</i></li>
          <li>HTML, CSS, JavaScript...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The JavaScript looks like that at the moment:

```
function show(x){

  x = document.querySelector('.expl').style.display ="block";

}
```

I have no idea of how to correctly use "this", but I tried it here, because it seemed to be right to me, but maybe I am completely wrong. I want to be able to add as many divs to the table as I want, but without changing the function. At the moment the only the div inside of the very first div gets the correct "style.display" if I "mouseenter" on EITHER of the outer divs.

Is that idea going into the right direction or is my approach wrong?

Comment: just use `this.style.display="block";` without `querySelector`. Final code `x=this.style.display="block";` for `show()` function.

Comment: In you show function try putting this: x.querySelector('.expl').style.display ="block"; instead of what currently is there.

Comment: Also, to explain whats happening here...by passing "this" as argument you are actually passing the Object of that html Tag. In you case it's DIVs. Using this object you can access/change properties of that DIV tag only.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It helped me understanding the use of "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to the actual element from where the click originated. So it refers to the `.box` elements.

Since the `.expl` is a descendant of the `.box` element you can search deeper inside it, through the `x`, and find the relevant `.expl` element.

So

```
function show(x){ // x refers to the .box element that was clicked
  x.querySelector('.expl').style.display ="block";
}
```

---

Working example

```js
function show(x) { // x refers to the .box element that was clicked
  x.querySelector('.expl').style.display = "block";
}

function hide(x) { // x refers to the .box element that was clicked
  x.querySelector('.expl').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="box box2" onmouseenter="show(this)" onmouseleave="hide(this)">
        <b>HTML</b>

        <div class="expl expl2" style="display:none" id="test">
          <ul>
            <li><b>Software</b></li>
            <li><i>HTML</i></li>
            <li>HTML, CSS, JavaScript...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="box box2" onmouseenter="show(this)" onmouseleave="hide(this)">
        <b>HTML</b>

        <div class="expl expl2" style="display:none" id="test2">
          <ul>
            <li><b>Software</b></li>
            <li><i>CSS</i></li>
            <li>HTML, CSS, JavaScript...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhh yes I tried this aswell, but it didn't work, because I didn't remove the ".document."-part. Thank you very much this is perfect :)

Answer (score -1):

Below is a function that can be used on any element that you want to show or hide on mouse enter.

Simply add the class: `triggerMouseHere` to make the div triggable by javascript when the mouse enters and leaves it

Add the class: `triggerChangeOnMouseEvent` to make the div visible/hidden when the mouse enters/leaves the parent div

```js
$(function() {
    $(".triggerMouseHere").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).find(".triggerChangeOnMouseEvent").first().show();
    });

    $(".triggerMouseHere").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).find(".triggerChangeOnMouseEvent").first().hide();
    });
  });
```

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="box box2 triggerMouseHere">
      <b>HTML</b>

      <div class="expl expl2 hidden triggerChangeOnMouseEvent" id="test">
        <ul>
          <li><b>Software</b></li>
          <li><i>HTML</i></li>
          <li class="triggerMouseHere">HTML, CSS, JavaScript...
            <div class="expl expl2 hidden triggerChangeOnMouseEvent" id="test">
              <ul>
                <li><b>Software</b></li>
                <li><i>HTML</i></li>
                <li class="triggerChangeOnMouseEvent">HTML, CSS, JavaScript...
                
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="box box2 triggerMouseHere">
      <b>HTML</b>

      <div class="expl expl2 hidden triggerChangeOnMouseEvent" id="test2">
        <ul>
          <li><b>Software</b></li>
          <li><i>CSS</i></li>
          <li>HTML, CSS, JavaScript...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Just a question, why don't you use `css` to show, hide the `child elements` ?

Comment: Just a heads up: the OP does not use jQuery (*and the question is not tagged as such*)